# Where to initialize data loading with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm using `react-navigation` and here is my structure :

The root stack navigator :

```
export const Root = StackNavigator({
Index: {
    screen: Index,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({

    }),
},
Cart: {
    screen: Cart,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: 'Votre panier',
        drawerLabel: 'Cart',
        drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon theme={{ iconFamily: 'FontAwesome' }} size={26} name="shopping-basket" color={tintColor} />
    }),
},
...
```

My structure looks like this :

> - StackNavigator (Root)
>
>   - DrawerNavigator (Index)
>
>     - TabNavigator
>
>       - MyPage
>       - MyPage (same page formatted with different datas)
>       - ...

So my question is, where do I load my data, initialize my application ? I need somewhere called once, called before the others pages.

The first page displayed in my application is the MyPage page. But as you can see, because of the TabNavigator, if I put my functions inside, it will be called many times.

Some will says in the splashscreen, but I'm using the main [splashscreen component](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen) and I don't have many controls over it.

I thought about my App.js where we create the provider, but I don't think this is a good idea ?

```
const MyApp = () => {

    //TODO We're loading the data here, I don't know if it's the good decision
    ApplicationManager.loadData(store);
    SplashScreen.hide();

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Root/>
        </Provider>
    ); 
};
```

What is the good way to do it ?

Comment: Do you want to pull fresh data every time you enter MyPage, MyPage (same page...), ... ?

Answer (score 3):

```
class MyApp extends Component {

  state = {
    initialized: false
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // if this is a promise, otherwise pass a callback to call when it's done
    ApplicationManager.loadData(store).then(() => {
      this.setState({ initialized: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { initialized } = this.state
    if (!initialized) {
      return <SplashScreen />
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store} >
        <Root />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed

Answer (score 2):

TabNavigator by default renders/loads all its child components at the same time, but if you set property `lazy: true` components will render only if you navigate. Which means your functions will not be called many times.

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator(
    {
      MyPage : {
        screen: MyPage
      },
      MyPage2 : {
        screen: MyPage,
        }
      }
    },
    {
        lazy: true
    }
);
```

If you use this structure and call fetching data inside of MyPage you can add logic in `componentWillReceiveProps` that will check is data already in store and/or is it changed before fetching new data. Calling your fetch functions from MyPage gives you the ability to pull fresh data on every page/screen visit or do "pull to refresh" if you need one.

You could also pull initial data in splashscreen time, I would just not recommend pulling all your app data, data for all screens, at that time since you probably don't need it all at once. You can do something like:

```
class MyApp extends Component {

  state = {
    initialized: false
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // if this is a promise, otherwise pass a callback to call when it's done
    ApplicationManager.loadData(store).then(() => {
      this.setState({ initialized: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { initialized } = this.state
    if (!initialized) {
      return null
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store} >
        <Root />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

class Root extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.hide();
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Your answer was complete, but @Alexander was the first to gave me the correct one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in `App.js` or where you initialize your `StackNavigator`. If I were you, I would put a loading screen, which would get replaced by the `StackNavigator` structure once the data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it in the App because you lose control. Sadly I haven't used react-navigation or redux but I see that the TabNavigator has a tabBarOnPress method, which I would use to trigger the loading. You can load every page data on demand.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#tabBarOnPress